# Does anyone know what this loop does

Tags: python

Suuupppeeeeerrrrrr noob question,

I am trying to deconstruct some python code, and I can figure out what this line does.  I know it cycles thru potentially 28 iterations but I can't figure out what the i%len does to question.

```
for i in range(t, t + 28):
    transmission.append(question[i%len(question)])
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are correct about the 28 iterations. For the second line, look into the `.append()` [list method](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), and the modulo (`%`) [operator](http://www.learnpython.org/en/Basic_Operators).

Answer (score 0):

The percent sign(%) is used to calculate the remainder. For example 3 % 2 = 1. In this case it's calculating the remainder of "i" divided by the length(len) of whatever "question" is.

Comment: Awesome thank you for your help!